# How can I print GMap.NET maps?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, .net-4.0, gmap.net

So there is GMapControl on form. I want to print map, and here is code

```
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument { DocumentName = "Map printing file" };
doc.PrintPage += DocOnPrintPage;
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog { Document = doc };
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) doc.Print();
```

and

```
private void DocOnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var img = View.gmap.ToImage();
    System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
}
```

I'm using `ToImage()` method, but it does not work as I want (it's like PrintScreen, because there are another objects like cursor, dialogbox, etc.) Is there any workaround to implement printing without this objects?

P.S. `Gmap.Net.Core` and `Gmap.Net.WindowForms` verison is 1.7.0.0, and .Net Framework version is 4.0 and I can't upgrade .Net Framework version, because some of clients are using Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was resolved by using temporary images.

```
string path = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName() + @".png";
_tmpImage = View.gmap.ToImage();
if (_tmpImage == null) return;
_tmpImage.Save(path);

PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument { DocumentName = "Map printing file" };
doc.PrintPage += DocOnPrintPage;
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog { Document = doc };
DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK) doc.Print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl called 'MyMap', then use this:

```
Dim ThisMap As New Bitmap(MyMap.Width, MyMap.Height)
MyMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, SavImg.Width, SavImg.Height))
```

You can then do what you want with 'ThisMap'.